# pywinauto NoPatternInterfaceError select value in ComboBox

Tags: pywinauto

I am getting **NoPatternInterfaceError** exception when trying to select a value from ComboBox

Any help will be much appreciated

```
batch_combobox = wnd_spec_obj.child_window(
    title='Batch class:',
    auto_id='27651',
    control_type='ComboBox').wait('exists enabled visible ready', timeout=50, 
retry_interval=0.25)

batch_combobox.select('Mail')
```

when i print the batch_combobox, i get

```
  uia_controls.ComboBoxWrapper - 'Batch class:', ComboBox
```

**workaround**

```
from pywinauto.controls.win32_controls import ComboBoxWrapper
ComboBoxWrapper(batch_combobox).select('Mail')
```

Comment: Yeah, it’s a WinForms combo box probably. This is known issue recently reported on GitHub.

Comment: Can be workarounded by using backend=“win32”

Comment: Setting the backend='win32' didn't work. All the methods I'd to find windows on my application was unable to locate the windows. Setting the backed='uia' made all my methods work. I added a workaround that worked to my question. Can you let me know if that is a right approach

Comment: Yeah, this is correct workaround. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Appreciate all your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in `pywinauto==0.6.6`. Please update and try again.